# how-to secure indexed content in vertex ai search based on the content permissions in the source application?

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai

Does vertex ai search provide a framework to index content permissions along with content? If no, then are there any suggestions on this topic? If yes, please point to relevant documentation. Thanks

I have not been able to find any documentation on this topic. The goal is to show search result based on the content permission provided by the source application for the search user.